# How to globalize a dummy argument from a function call

Tags: fortran

How to globalize a dummy argument from a function call?

I have the below code in Fortran

```
A(a,b)  // here a and b are the values filling from function call but they are not declared any where
.
.
.
B(a.b) // same variable passing again to this function call also.
```

here the problem is the values from *a* and *b* are not maintaining for second call. it's returning a garbage. Even I tried this using ***common*** but its not accepting to globalize dummy arguments. How to do it?

Comment: is that "." instead of "," a typo in the question, or perhaps the reason you are getting garbage?

Answer (score 1):

You say that "`a` and `b` are the values filling from function call but they are not declared anywhere" - even though I'm still trying to figure out exactly what you're trying to do, this statement throws up all sorts of red flags.  This is Fortran - you *need* to declare them (see note).

I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish - chances are, though, "globalize" isn't what you want to do - we should be striving to eliminate global variables in our code.

Note: Yes, Fortran (or really, FORTRAN) supports implicit declaration of variables.  However, this is a relic from the days of punch cards and dumb terminals.  **Do Not** use implicit typing anywhere - your code should *always* include `implicit none`, and you should declare your variables appropriately.

Comment: They dropped the all caps spelling sometime around Fortran 77.

Comment: Yes they did - what I was trying to say is that even though more modern Fortran might still support implicit declaration, it's linked in my mind to the obsolete style.  All-caps spelling is for older versions of the language - so is fixed-formatting, computed GOTO statements, and implicit declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SAVE` declaration to store the state across invocations of the subroutine or function.

Comment: I have no idea what the question means, but it does talk about a problem with dummy arguments.  Can you give more detail as to how the `save` attribute will solve the problem, as it's an attribute that cannot apply to dummy arguments?

Comment: Usually using Intent (InOut) should work. I had used save but for a local variable, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy variables are by nature, that: dummy arguments. They are simply placeholders, and when a function is called, they get replaced with whatever you passed the function when calling it. lets look at a silly example:

```
integer function add(x,y)
  integer :: x, y
  add = x + y
end
```

so now, you can call this function in many ways. lets say you want to add a and b:

```
integer :: a, b, c

a = 3
b = 4
c = add(a,b)
```

here, a will take the position of x in the function, and b will take the position of y. c will have the value of 7. you could have just as easily done:

```
integer :: c

c = add(3,4)
```

with the same results. as you can see, globalizing dummy arguments is meaningless.